# How to efficiently mass update in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, xml

I'm working on an integration with our warehouse. We receive an XML message with all our SKUs and their inventory levels. For each SKU I need to update the inventory level in my rails app. However, every time I request the XML message, the processing is very slow, to the point where the browser times out. I suspect this is because I have to do a look up for each SKU by name and update the inventory level for it. There should be around 1000 SKUs returned in the XML, this means 2 lookups for each SKU and 1 save.

Is there a way for me to optimize the performance for this integration? 
I am fairly new to Rails but I feel like there should be a more efficient way of doing this.

Example XML:

```
<InventoryXML>
<Item> 
  <ItemID>ABC-12-2345</ItemID> 
  <ItemQty>14</ItemQty> 
  <Warehouses>
    <Warehouse> 
      <Name>Constitution</Name>
      <Quantity>9</Quantity> 
    </Warehouse>
    <Warehouse> 
      <Name>Vegas</Name>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity> 
    </Warehouse>
    <Warehouse> 
      <Name>Atlanta</Name>
      <Quantity>4</Quantity> 
    </Warehouse>
  </Warehouses> 
</Item>
</InventoryXML>
```

Code:

```
def process_inventory
    @doc.xpath('//Item').each do |item|
        name = item.xpath('//ItemID').text
        warehouses = item.xpath('//Warehouses')
        warehouses.xpath('Warehouse').each do |warehouse|
            if warehouse.xpath('Name').text == "Vegas"
                self.update_inventory_for_sku(2, name, warehouse.xpath('Quantity').text.to_i)
            elsif warehouse.xpath('Name').text == "PA"
                self.update_inventory_for_sku(1, name, warehouse.xpath('Quantity').text.to_i)
            end
        end
    end
    return "Succesfully updated SKU inventory"
end

def update_inventory_for_sku(vendor_id, name, quantity)
    sku = VendorSku.where({vendor_id: vendor_id, name: name}).first
    if sku
        sku.update_attributes(inventory_quantity: quantity)
    else
        self.hub_error_message += "\nSKU not found: " + name.to_s + "for vendor_id: " + vendor_id.to_s
    end
end
```

Comment: Do you have a combined index on the `vendor_id` and `name` columns of your `vendor_skus` database table? Do you need to run validations and update timestamps when runing this task? Or is it an option to use [`update_all`](http://apidock.com/rails/v4.2.1/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all)?

Comment: I don't think update_all is possible since I will have different inventory levels for each SKU. What exactly do you mean with combined index? I believe my index is just .id

Comment: Sure, but you could combine it with `where`: Because `VendorSku.where(vendor_id: vendor_id, name: name).update_all(inventory_quantity: quantity)` is way faster than loading each record first and then update its attributes. In combination with an appropriate index on the database this could lead to an significant performance boost.

Comment: I updated my code and gave it a shot but my browser is still timing out. I'll double check if there's an index on those fields. Otherwise I might have to resort to a background job of some sort?

Comment: Both fields are indexed but it still times out. Any options left to improve performance?

Comment: Did you try `update_all`? Did you consider running this task in the background with a tool like DelayedJob or Sidekiq?

Comment: Yea I used update_all. Looking into delayedjob now.